# How to add an **existent** security group to a folder?

Tags: permissions

How to add an **existent** security group to a folder with the read/write permissions?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve? What is your aim, why do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to grant a group the read/write permissions on a folder.

Comment: You want the chown command

Answer (score 0):

A file or directory can only have **one** group associated with it.

You change that group from the terminal using this command:

```
chgrp GROUPNAME FILENAME
```

Of course you have to replace `GROUPNAME` with the desired group and `FILENAME` with the file or directory you want to modify. Depending on your current permissions for this file, you might have to run the command as root (using `sudo`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So I assume that the group will be on raw by default?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "on raw". By default, the owner is the user that created the file and the group is that user's native group (same name as username).

Comment: And if this answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the round grey tick symbol on the left of it to mark your question as solved.

Comment: Sorry about that, I mean "r/w" not raw.

Comment: The *group* and the *group permissions* are slightly different. The *group* is the actual name of the user group that a file is associated with. The *group permissions* describe the **r**ead/**w**rite/e**x**ecute permissions for this file for members of the associated group. The default group is the native group of the user who created the file. The default group permissions of a new file a normal user creates is 'rwx', when root creates a file it's 'r-x'. You find out what permissions a new file created by your current user would get using the command `umask -S`.